What is the recommended way to integrate payments into an android app which doesn't host a server?
I have an app which can be categorised as "utility" app. Due to the nature of the utility it doesn't need connecting to a server. So, essentially, the app can be used completely offline. 
Now, if I were to introduce payments into this app - what are the steps that I should be following? I am guessing there needs to be someway to track that the person has made a payment so that if the person uninstalls and install the app he/she can still continue using the paid version of the app. So, is my only option to have a server side that maintains the state of the user and thus making the app an "online" app?

Server or using Google Play for the payments is the only way (which just means Google is the server).  When you uninstall, everything is wiped.  Reinstalling it won't bring back the data.  So you need some remote source to tell it that they already paid.
BTW, legally you may have to use Google's payment system to be in the Play Store.  Consult a lawyer about Google's terms of service in your country to see if you can use alternative methods, and if you need to use it in other regions, we aren't legal experts who can guide you on that.  But Google tends to insist on it.

I think the most straightforward way is to leverage the Google Play billing system. You need to integrate the Google Play billing library into your app and follow the flow they suggest in order to make a payment/subscription.
The good thing is that through the library you can recognize whether the account (the gmail account associated to the phone where the app is executed) has already made a purchase, even though the user uninstall the app and maybe reinstall it later. In this case you don't need to use a dedicated server, the state is handled by Google.
In the Play Console you can designate some gmail accounts that can make "fake" purchases for testing purpose and such testing purchases can be revoked from the same console.
As also reported by @Gabe, you should verify Google's suggestion related to your country.
